# Conditional color change in a chart

Tags: format, conditional-statements, jasper-reports, charts, ireport

Is it possible to create a bar chart with red colour when the values are negative and green colour when the values are positive? Is Conditional formatting within a chart in iReport possible?

If so, could anyone suggest a way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but maybe someone needs it. Paste a green chart in one group and paste a red chart in another group( changeing the series color).

Of course both charts are connected to the same query. Then in the print expression of each group check like if (num<0) print this group, then in the other group header's print expression check if (num>0) print this group

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with @Rika

I don't think there is a way to that, 'cuz since the graph is a whole object you don't get to get access to them bars individually. iReport has some limitations, u know.

Comment: Use comments instead of answer for such kind of posts.

Comment: If I could. They say: "ask, answer, edit" for newbies. I'm trying here, but thanks!